# How do I escape quotes in a SQL file?

Tags: sql

I have a big SQL file with lines like this

```
(NULL, "190", "1986-07-23", "Kyoko's Gift ! "What , You Mean it's For Me?"", "Godai gets depressed over the rain, remembering that some of the worst events of his life have occured on rainy days. Kozue visits Maison Ikkoku and her skirt gets stained so she and Kyoko have snacks together while they wait for the skirt to dry. Kozue asks about Godai and learns that Kyoko is a widow. Kyoko remembers trying to flirt with Soichiro when she was in high school . After Kozue leaves, Godai runs into Kyoko, and she invites him to share an umbrella with her as they head home.", "0", "25", "18", "1"),
```

the problem is that there is a part of that line with double quotes:

```
,"Kyoko's Gift ! "What , You Mean it's For Me?"",
```

And I always get a error, the problem is that there are alot of lines like this, Is there a good way to escape all the necessary quotes to make it work properly?

Comment: `''` instead of `'`

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL file" ?  How are you processing it?

Comment: @devlincarnate What i mean by that is that I have alot of other lines similar to that and I want to fix them all at once not one by one

Comment: @PedroBarbosa: What *lines*? A database has no SQL *files*. It has tables. So what are you actually talking about?

Comment: For you to be able to process all lines at once you need to know how to process one line. Do you know already how to escape one line? Can you please define exactly what your problem is?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry if I was misleading, What I mean by lines is that I have a .sql file with lots and lots of values to "INSERT INTO"

Comment: Okay, a file with incorrect insert statements, because of the quotes. The first thing wrong is that the string limiter in SQL is the *single* quote `'`. So when generating the file one must use these. To escape them in strings such as in `it's`, you need them twice: `it''s`. So the whole string becomes `'Kyoko's Gift ! "What , You Mean it''s For Me?"`. If you cannot generate the file anew, but must work with the one given, you'd either have to manually change this or write a programm to do that, and find some algorithm to tell string limiters from the in-string quotes (which is not that easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server, try this:

```
'Kyoko''s Gift ! What, You Mean it''s For Me?'
```

Comment: But I have alot of other lines similar to that, is there a way to fix all of them? instead of one at a time?

Comment: how do you expecting the results?

Comment: Look into regular expressions ... match what you're looking for and replace it. You may be able to use Notepad++ for this, it will let you process all lines at once: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of queries that need to have quotes escaped, you'll need to use Find/Replace in SSMS or a text editor to replace the quotes with properly escaped quotes.

First replace single quotes `'` with double single quotes `''`.
Then replace double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`.

In the end, you should have single quotes around strings, like so:
`'Foo Bar'`
And your apostrophes should be escaped, like so:
`'It''s my Foo Bar'`